# Creating a new column based on a condition from 2 different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, case, inner-join

I have 2 tables, I am forming a query to extract the data with a new column showing the type of customer (Free/Premium)
I have attached the picture where there in one table there is info about the name and in another we have payment info.
I want the result as shown in the form of a third column TYPE and based on the payment info from table B it should show Premium else Null.
I am trying to use CASE & JOIN but i am not able to formulate the query. Please help[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . I think you want the `type` to be based on the existence of a matching row in `b`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from b where b.user_id = a.user_id)
             then 'Premium' else 'Free'
        end) as type
from a;
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that customers that have made at least one payment are "Premium", and others are "Free". If so, you can use `exists` and a `case` expression:

```
select a.*
    case when exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.userid = a.userid)
        then 'Premium'
        else 'Free'
    end as type
from tablea a
```

Comment: This one forgot the comma after a.*  --->  a.*,